# Javascript - exclude everything outside a certain form tag

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, submit, ejs

I have a page that shows restaurant reviews and each review has a like button on it. Each button is inside a form tag that has hidden input fields of review ID and user ID. The problem is when I submit the form, everything inside and outside a certain form tag on that page is submitted to the back-end and I don't know what review just got liked to update the database and the front-end. Is there any way I can send data only inside the form tag? Thanks.

**The form tag, each review will have a form like this**

```
<form style="padding-top: 5px;" onsubmit="ajax_helpful_vote()">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<%= user._id %>">
    <input type="hidden" name=<%= review._id %> value="<%= review._id %>">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id=<%= review._id %>>
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> Helpful
    </button>
</form>
```

**ajax function to send data to server**

```
function ajax_helpful_vote(form_id) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var formArray= $("#"+form_id).serializeArray();
    var data={};
    for (var index in formArray){
        data[formArray[index].name]= formArray[index].value;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: '/helpful_vote' ,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (dataR) {
            // disable helpful button
            document.getElementById(dataR.liked_review_id.toString()).disabled = true;
            // update number of votes
            $('#' + dataR.liked_review_id.toString() + "-text").prepend("You and ");
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log('Error: ' + error.message);
        }
    });
}
```

I tried to give the form a name/id and in the ajax function, get data of that form using the name/id but it redirects me to a page which has parameters of the input fields and doesn't send any data to the back-end. That means the ajax function is never fired therefore it reloads the page with a default get method.

```
<% }else{
var text_id = review._id + "-text";
var form_id = review._id + "-form";
 %>
 <p style="color: green; padding-top: 5px" id=<%= text_id %>><%= review.liked_by.length %> people find this review helpful</p>
 <form id="<%=form_id%>" style="padding-top: 5px;" onsubmit="ajax_helpful_vote(<%=form_id.toString()%>)">
   <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<%= user._id %>">
   <input type="hidden" name=<%= review._id %> value="<%= review._id %>">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id=<%= review._id %>>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> Helpful
   </button>
 </form>
```

**The rendered form tag**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, so the problem is not the function but how the form-id is passed to the function. Instead of `onsubmit="ajax_helpful_vote(<%=form_id.toString()%>)"`, I should have `onsubmit="ajax_helpful_vote('<%=form_id.toString()%>')"`. It should be single quote instead of double quote.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting an `id` to the form then `var formArray= $("form#some_id").serializeArray();`

To demonstrate how that works:

```js
function ajax_helpful_vote(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var formArray= $("form").serializeArray();
    console.log(formArray)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="outside" value="outside"></input>
<form id="myForm" style="padding-top: 5px;" onsubmit="ajax_helpful_vote(event)">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="user_test"/>
    <input type="hidden" name=name1"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> Helpful
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Tried that, it reloads the page with the parameters from the input fields and doesn't send any data to the back-end

Comment: Do you mean `formArray` is null or empty?

Comment: Well, I tried to print out the `formArray` but the page is reloaded immediately so I can't see whether it's empty or not.

Comment: But I did a `console.log` in the back-end and it didn't print out anything

Comment: The same problem, is there any way I can see whether the function is actually fired or not?

Comment: @TriNguyen, the function is firing and that is why the `console` is showing the data. If you want to submit the form just remove `event.preventDefault()` from the function......thanks

Comment: I understand your code but if you look at what I have updated, I'm passing the form id to the function. This id  is the review id. I don't think the problem is the ajax function but the form opening tag where I pass the id to the function

Comment: I have updated a picture of the form tag as well as the ajax function

Answer (score 0):

The form submits immediately. That's why the AJAX call is not fired. You should prevent the form from submission first. Since you're using jQuery, there is an easy way.

Remove the `onsubmit` handler from your form's HTML, and bind it using jQuery's event handling:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  ajax_helpful_vote();
})

function ajax_helpful_vote() {
  ...
}
```

Also, remove the last line `event.preventDefault();` from the function `ajax_helpful_vote`, which will throw an error as `event` will not be defined over there.

Comment: I think the function is never fired, I put an `alert` inside a function and I can't see anything

Comment: `ajax_helpful_vote` does not fire so I get the default get method with input parameters. Please check edit.

Comment: I checked the log, there is no post request.